# Why when selecting a different object in the Hierarchy the camera is stuttering?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I removed all the scripts from all the GameObjects for testing the problem.

I have a Camera name Fly Camera. ( Main Camera disabled not in use only one Camera)
On the Fly Camera I attached a new simple script that mnove the camera between two points. And also added some cubes.

In the Hierarchy when selecting with the mouse the Fly Camera while the game is running the camera will move smooth from side to side. But if I select in the Hierarchy while the game is running any other GameObject then the camera will stuttering. Or at least in the Game window it will looks like stuttering.

I'm not sure if it's normal but seems a bit strange that if you selected another object in the hierarchy it will stutter in the game window view.

The script: Attached to the Fly Camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(-40, 0, -50);
    private Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(40, 0, -50);
    public float speed = 1.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pos1, pos2, (Mathf.Sin(speed * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
    }
}
```

I opened the Profiler when the game is running and this is three screenshots.
The first when selecting the Fly Camera in the Hierarchy:

[image: Profiler when selecting the fly camera]

The second screenshot show after selecting another GameObject in the Hierarchy just a bit before the profiler change it's in the middle:

[image: Profiler second or two after selecting another gameobject]

Last screenshot is about 10 seconds after selecting the other gameobject and that make the camera stuttering: The stuttering start once selecting another object in the profiler the change take some seconds to show:

[image: Profiler after selecting another gameobject]

Then if I will change and select the camera again it will move smooth and the profiler will be again like in screenshot 1.

And a screenshot of the profiler editor enabled and stats enabled:

[image: Profiler editor enabled stats enabled]

Comment: Looks OK, could you enable Profile Editor and Stats in the game view?

Comment: @shingo Enabled both editor profiler and stats and added a screenshot of it to my question.

Comment: You see, something spends a lot of time. what's that?

Comment: @shingo Not sure what's spending too much time. Something in the script ?

Comment: You can click on the graph, there are information in the bottom part of the profiler.

Comment: @shingo I see that the Gfx.ProcessCommands take about 103.64ms but not sure what's that.

Comment: And I see that Update Scene also take more then 100ms

Comment: @shingo Can you give me a clue ? The problem is with the ram memory ?

Comment: Not sure, the screenshot is the only clue for me, and not reproduce in my machine.